# mongodb- how to find the closest value faster

Tags: mongodb

db knows that "time" is ascending.

This is what I done:

```
var t = 123;
var before = db.test.find({ "time": {$lte:t}});
var after = db.test.find({ "time": {$gt:t}});
before[before.size()-1]
after[0]
```

But, when the database is super huge, it's time-consuming!

It seems that db searches from _id(beginning) to _id(end).

Comment: Do you want to get two closest values one greater and one lower or just the closest value?

Comment: I want to get two, but getting the closet value is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have index created on `time` attribute? If you're missing it, then mongo will always be forced to do the entire db lookup.

To know how many documents mongo checked run `db.collection_name.find({ time: { $gt: 50 } }).explain()`. `nscannedObjects`, `cursor` attributes will indicate whether it seached the whole db or only a subset.

In case you have index and it works slowly it's also possible your index(es) doesn't fit into memory. More on it can be found here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the closest value, this aggregation will do the job:

```
var t = 12;
db.test.aggregate([{
    $project: {
      time: 1,
      diff: {
        $abs: {
          $subtract: [t, '$time']
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    $sort: {
      diff: 1
    }
  }, {
    $limit: 1
  }
]);
```

Note: [`$abs`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/abs/) only comes in Mongo 3.2 or higher.